# The pager property doesn't function once the rowNum property is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am new to using jqGrid! When displaying the data in form of a table, I set the rowNum property to display 5 rows but when I do so the pagination{pager: true} stops working.

Here is the jqGrid function and the data that is being displayed along with the incorrect table that is being displayed.

```js
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css">
    @*<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.15.5/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function () {
            "use strict";
         $("#table").jqGrid({

            url: '@Url.Action("Data","Cart")',
            mtype: "GET",
            datatype: "json",
            
            colModel: [
                { name:"ID", label:"ID", width: 150 },
                { name:"Name", label:"Product", width:150 },
                { name:"Description", label:"Description", width: 150 },
                { name:"Price", label:"Price", width: 150 }
             ],
             guiStyle: "bootstrap4",
            viewrecords: true,
             toppager: true,
             pager: true,
             rowNum: 5,
             rowList: [10, 20, 30],
             rownumbers: true,
            caption: "Products Table",
         });
            /*jQuery("#table").setGridParam({ rowNum: 10 }).trigger("reloadGrid");*/
            $("#table").jqGrid('navGrid', { edit: true, add: true, delete: true });
        });
    </script>
```

[This is the displayed table with pagination not working!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEFv5.png)

[This is the Data to be Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRHad.png)

Json Data:
{"rows":[{"ID":1,"Name":"watch","Description":"A piece of wearable on hands","Price":500},{"ID":2,"Name":"clothes","Description":"a peice to show colorful you","Price":1000},{"ID":3,"Name":"shoes","Description":"a wearble for your feet","Price":20000},{"ID":6,"Name":"xyz","Description":"xxgxvb","Price":0},{"ID":12,"Name":"V-Neck T-Shirt","Description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.","Price":5326},{"ID":16,"Name":"hoodie","Description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.","Price":3234},{"ID":21,"Name":"Beanie","Description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.","Price":200},{"ID":22,"Name":"Belt","Description":"A classic Wear to stay in your Limits","Price":345},{"ID":23,"Name":"Cap","Description":"Getting A HAir Loss, Save Your Dignity","Price":243},{"ID":24,"Name":"Sunglassess","Description":"Increse Your Style","Price":100},{"ID":25,"Name":"Long Sleeve tee","Description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.","Price":243},{"ID":26,"Name":"Single ","Description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.","Price":243},{"ID":27,"Name":"thongs","Description":"Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.","Price":2342},{"ID":28,"Name":"Red Shirts","Description":" Oooo LAlala ","Price":3242},{"ID":29,"Name":"Logo Collection","Description":"best Thing to Have ","Price":325333},{"ID":30,"Name":"pushkar","Description":"worth Buying","Price":20000},{"ID":31,"Name":"yam","Description":"A piece of wearable on hands","Price":10}]}

Answer (score 0):

This is so since you have a wrong value for **total** property (total pages) in your json response. [See docs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#json-data) how your response should look like:

**EDIT**

Based on your response you missed to put the total, page, and records property

Let by example you have 500 record in the table and you want to make the pagination of 10 records per page. In this case your response from the server should look like this:

```
{
    "records": "500", // the total records in table
    "total": 50, // total pages based on the nomber of rows
    "page" : 1, // current page
    "rows" : [
         {"ID":1,"Name":"watch","Description":"A piece of wearable on hands","Price":500},
         {"ID":2,"Name":"clothes","Description":"a peice to show colorful you","Price":1000},
          ...] // current data of 10 records
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the solution!

Comment: I have seen a few solutions which work without the total: "total pages" property, and they work fine. Why isn't my code working!

Comment: Maybe since you use server side response. In order to identify the problem, please post your server side response

Comment: I tried it all and debugged each thing, also manually checked if the JSON data was fetched, each bit was working still the pagination didn't work..    Now I have some different methods which have got the pagination working, still it would be good to know, what fault is making this happen

Comment: Post your json response from serevr and I will try to identify the problem.

Comment: I have added the JSON data in the question!

Comment: Thanks, Tony, I appreciate it, but as I mentioned earlier I have seen a video that uses the same methodology and gains the desired results....I myself have tried the total property after wards and gained the results, it's just that I wanted to know that why is it not working with me when working g for others  :-)